# How to read text transitions in a Powerpoint file via C#

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint

I am using C# and VS2008. If I open a pre-existing Powerpoint file in C#, what do I need to do to be able to read what the text animations are for each slide? I think I can use Office Primary Interop Assemblies to handle PowerPoint, but what property would be used for text animations?

Comment: Better describe exactly what you mean by text transitions. Sstrictly speaking, in PPT slides have transitions, text and other shapes do not, though they can be animated ... I'm guessing that's what you're after?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really pretty useless at animation coding, but this should give you a start:

Each slide has a TimeLine

The TimeLine has a MainSequence that contains most of the animations on the slide (there are also any number of interactive sequences, but let's not complicate things that far).

Each member(.Item) of the MainSequence has various properties like .EffectType and also .Shape (which points back to the shape the animation is applied to.

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).TimeLine.MainSequence

  ' how many animations are there in the main sequence?
  Debug.Print .Count

  For x = 1 to .Count
    ' What kind of effect is it?
    Debug.Print .Item(x).EffectType
    ' What shape is this animation applied to?
    Debug.Print .Item(x).Shape.Name
  Next
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful in getting me started.